# How to cast from Editable to float

Tags: android, casting

I want to make the text inside the EditText converted to float

anyone know how to cast from EditText.getText() to float?

---

I make this solution
float salary= new Float(salaryET.getText().toString());

and it work ok

thanks for every body

Comment: You should learn java before getting into android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = EditText.getText().toString;
try{
     Float f = new Float(str);
     System.out.println("Float value is: = " + f);
}catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

use the above code to convert editable to float. Also added the try catch block for any exceptions while converting.

**Updated:::**

```
Float f = Float.parseFloat(str);//you can also use this
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Float f = Float.valueOf(EditText.getText().toString());
```

this  code to convert `EditText` text to float

Comment: EditText.getText() replaced with EditText.getText().toString()